# writing to a data outfile mysql

Tags: mysql, export, select-into-outfile

This is a bit confusing to me. I am trying to export records out of my database into a csv file using mysql on AWS.

I do the select:

```
select BusinessName into outfile '/tmp/test.csv' from contractors limit 2;
```

and I get a message back

```
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I then go to /tmp to see the file and I don't see it. What I do find is:

```
/tmp/systemd-private-bc19608036e44476bfd3ef62c52ed14a-mariadb.service-jvEm06/tmp/test.csv
```

What I would really like is to be able to have the file go to my home directory but I am not sure where or where mysql is putting all the garbage at the beginning of the file. I am figuring this is a setting some where.

Any ideas?

Comment: MySQL itself stores the outfile woth strictly specified pathname (or fails due to some reason). So this is AWS issue. Check real SQL text received by MySQL in General log. Study AWS documentation about this issue.

Comment: Kindly check on MySQL server on same path

/tmp/test.csv

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA I have and I cannot find a sitting. I can load from a directory of my choosing but not export.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. Thank you @Akina I looked closer in the logs it seems it was an odd permissions issue on the directory I was using. fixed now.